# OpenAM Conditional Login Url

Tags: authentication, openam

I'm using openAM 10.0.0 and the admin guide mention it support conditional login (just no on console):
com.forgerock.agents.conditional.login.url

Then I configure agent as local config:
com.forgerock.agents.conditional.login.url[0]= songjing.com|http://openam.songjing.com:8080/openam/UI/Login

om.forgerock.agents.conditional.login.url[1]= brandA.songjing.com|http://openam.songjing.com:8080/openam/UI/LoginBrandA

When I browse to brandA.songjing.com, it still go back to http://openam.songjing.com:8080/openam/UI/Login login page.  I thought it is cause by 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url[0] = http://openam.songjing.com:8080/openam/UI/Login
And remark it.

Then end up with error say com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url not found.

I try with web agent 3.0.4 and 3.1 for apahche httpd, both not working

Any help?

Rgds
SJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  web agent 3.0.4 not support conditional login url.

for web agent 3.1 the key is:
com.forgerock.agents.conditional.login.url

and for j2ee agent 3.1 the key is
com.sun.identity.agents.config.conditional.login.url

and due to I use virtual server, I need configure fqdn mapping:
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.mapping[branda.com] = branda.com